# Implementing equals & hashcode for ArrayList.contains() not working

Tags: java

My attempt to customize the method contains of ArrayList, I used Eclipse to generate these methods inside a class TaskCandidateListItemDo

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result;

    if (keyValue == null) {
        result += 0;
    } else {
        result += keyValue.hashCode();
    }

    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    TaskOverrideItemDo other = (TaskOverrideItemDo) obj;

    if (keyValue == null) {
        if (other.keyValue != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!keyValue.equals(other.keyValue)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

And here's is how I use it

```
taskCandidateList = (List<TaskCandidateListItemDo>) namedQuery.list();

for (TaskOverrideItemDo taskOverrideItemDo : validateOverrideListSearchCriteriaDo
        .getTaskOverrideItemDoList()) {

    if (taskCandidateList.contains(taskOverrideItemDo.getKeyValue())) {
       // do some code
    }
}
```

My list declared as followed

```
private List<TaskCandidateListItemDo> taskCandidateList;
```

The // do some code inside the if statement is never executed even if keyValue exist. Also, the break point wouldnt stop at the equals method..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
if (taskCandidateList.contains(taskOverrideItemDo)) {
```

Without `getKeyValue()`, I suppose it returns the value of the field `keyValue` (and your `equals` method compares only `TaskCandidateListItemDo` because of:

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

As alternative you may support comparison with the type of `keyValue` inside the `equals` method.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
    return false;
}
```

Assuming this is from Hibernate, the *actual* objects you get back may well be of some byte-code-manipulated subclass of `TaskCandidateListItemDo`.

Of course, you should be able to tell that with a debugger. Just put a break-point (or logging) on that `return false`...

Comment: @JoopEggen: Or possibly a `LinkedHashSet`, depending on whether order is important. But let's work out the equality part first :) If there's a small number of results, it's not going to matter.

Comment: was just wondering whats the impact of passing TaskOverrideItemDo whilst the ArrayList is TaskCandidateListItemDo? mind you, i changed this to passing TaskCandidateListItemDo to this array list but same results

Comment: @sonx: Without knowing what your names mean, it's quite hard to tell, to be honest...

Comment: despite the naming, its two individual objects but both contain a property keyValue. They are both persistable

Comment: @sonx: It's still hard to tell exactly what's going on, to be honest. With partial bits of one class and no knowledge of the other, diagnosing things is hard. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would really help.