# Compatibility Issue - Java 1.7 to 1.6

Tags: java, compatibility

We have a web application that is compiled in Java 1.6 but we are trying to run this with 1.7 to find out any issues that we might encounter before we migrate the code to 1.7 permanently.

I do see that the application behaves differently on some screens between 1.7 and 1.6. We are consistently able to reproduce that by flip flopping the JRE version. Our application uses a lot of list and the issue, so far I can tell, is around the list operations. I haven't been exactly able to pin point the issue, but I am debugging through it. Just want to know if there is any "Known" issues with ArrayList between 1.6 and 1.7.

For those of you needing more detail, here is the issue.

We have a validation framework that validates the Model with the XML based rules and if any errors are found, those errors are stored in the database and then shown to the users. If the user fixes the errors and runs revalidation, the fixed error are supposed to go away (removed from the list). They do on version 1.6 but with version 1.7, the fixed errors don't go away and so it appears that a new error keeps getting added to the list of errors and gets persisted, thus everytime the user runs re-validation, the errors are duplicated.

Comment: Do you have any snippets of code where the list is being added to and removed from, that you can add into the body of your question? Also, have you recompiled against 1.7, or are you just merely pointing a 1.6 built JAR against 1.7?

Comment: No, there are no "Known issues with ArrayList between 1.6 and 1.7".  You can search Oracle, for example: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/2col/6u34-bugfixes-1733379.html.  If "ArrayList" is behaving "differently" ... you need to *debug your application".  SUGGESTION: Try reproducing the problem with some JUnit tests.  ALSO: be sure to see if you've done anything tricky with [hashCode()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838276/implementing-equals-hashcode-for-arraylist-contains-not-working)